# php Contact Form Coding Issues

Tags: php, forms, parentheses

I'm trying to create php code for an existing html form. When I try to create the code, it seems to have a problem with the closing parentheses, can anyone help?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['your_name'])) {
$your_name = $_POST['your_name'];

if (isset($_POST['your_email'])) {
$your_email = $_POST['your_email'];

if (isset($_POST['subject'])) ;
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

if (isset($_POST['message'])) ;
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "email.co.uk";
$subject = "New Message";

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $your_name);
echo "Your message has been sent";

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] to get you started.

Comment: This is a basic PHP syntax issue.  You should go through an introductory tutorial.

Comment: can people help me with the answer instead of voting down on the post. I don't see what else needs to be explained

Comment: You should be getting parse errors, close off the braces properly

Comment: And mail's From: expects an email, not a name so that may end up being rejected or treated as spam

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because you are using `;` in every `if` statement instead of `if { .. }` statements try this code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['your_name'])) {
$your_name = $_POST['your_name'];
} 

if (isset($_POST['your_email'])) {
$your_email = $_POST['your_email'];
}

if (isset($_POST['subject'])) {
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
}

if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
$message = $_POST['message'];
}

$to = "email.co.uk";
$subject = "New Message";

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $your_name);
echo "Your message has been sent";

?>
```

Comment: @user3015137 if it resolves your issue please prefer by accepting the right answer